# Why is fixed position elements being cut off on full-screen iPhone experience when multiple tabs are open?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, css-position, mobile-safari

I have a full-screen, non-scrollable interactive experience with fixed-position UI elements over top of a canvas. This experience works just fine in every browser that I've tested, however on iPhone, when there are multiple tabs open, the top of the page is being cut off.

Here's a very simplified code example...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVEOgw

```html
<style>
  #interface {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  
  #logo {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  #nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 200;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  #background {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #333;
  }
</style>
<div id="interface">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.grandinroad.com/wcsstore/images/GrandinRoad/logo.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <button>&lt; Previous</button> | <button>Next &gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="background">
  <!-- BACKGROUND -->
</div>
```

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Hi Jake, you'll need to add a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question in order to get reliable answers. Otherwise we're just guessing, and your question risks being closed as "off-topic".

Comment: I updated my question with a minimal code example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue with the bottom-aligned fixed-position element -- apparently I was using a CSS hack to force GPU acceleration, so that was causing the browser to render my fixed position elements incorrectly.

```
.force-gpu {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: This saved me so much time!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you are relying on a 100% height screen and you position your elements bottom: 0 ??
In that case, you should read this article as the 100vh does not cover your complete viewport in iOS 8: http://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html

Comment: This is exactly the same bug but I'm not using vh units. I'll post a minimal code example in a couple minutes. Did you ever find a fix for this issue?

Comment: I was able to fix my issue with the bottom-aligned fixed-position element -- apparently I was using a CSS hack to force GPU acceleration, so that was causing the browser to render my fixed position elements incorrectly. So now, the only issue I'm having is that the page gets cut off on the top when the user has multiple tabs open. I have updated my question with a code example.